# Sorting an array of objects on both ascending and descending order on same click

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, sorting, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects:

```
var arr = [{
  title: "finance",
  book: "book1"
},
{
  title: "nature",
  book: "book2"
},
{
  title: "programming",
  book: "book3"
}]
```

HTML:

```
<th><a href="#" ng-click="controller.sortTitle()">TITLE</a></th>
```

Right now I have implemented a basic sorting logic below

JAVASCRIPT(AngularJS controller):

```
self.sortTitle = function () {
    self.arr= self.arr.sort((a, b) => (a.title > b.title) ? 1 : -1);
}
```

This JavaScript function is currently sorting it in ascending order only based on title. How do I write a logic that sorts it on either order, i.e. click1 should sort it in ascending and click2 should reverse and set it in descending? Basically reversing the sort everytime it is clicked.

Comment: reverse the `>` to `<` and create a variable that can store the currently sort order.

Comment: Use a closure, and make the sorting function [generic](https://jsfiddle.net/nadg5wty/),

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a property on `self` like `isAscending` and default to true or false (whatever you want initially) based on which sort order will be executed and flip `isAscending` every time the sort fn runs.

```
self.isAscending = true;

self.sortTitle = function () {
 if(self.isAscending){ 
   self.arr= self.arr.sort((a, b) => (a.title > b.title) ? 1 : -1);
 }else{
   self.arr= self.arr.sort((a, b) => (a.title > b.title) ? -1 : 1);
 }
 self.isAscending = !self.isAscending;
}
```

Comment: That's great. Thanks.

Comment: Glad it helped @AshishVerma :)

Answer (score 2):

It probably would make sense to have a `reusable` function you can call to do the sorting for you which also accepts a `direction parameter`:

```js
var arr = [{ title: "finance", book: "book1" }, { title: "nature", book: "book2" }, { title: "programming", book: "book3" }]

let sortBy = (arr, p, o=1) => [...arr].sort((a,b) => a[p].localeCompare(b[p]) * o)

console.log(sortBy(arr, 'title'))
console.log(sortBy(arr, 'title', -1))
console.log(sortBy(arr, 'book'))
console.log(sortBy(arr, 'book', -1))
```

You can replace the last param to deal with `asc/desc` if you need to.

Also since you are comparing strings the recommended way is to use [String.localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) simply due to the amount of options it supports which almost always come in handy (sorting `book10` vs `book1` for example)

Answer (score 1):

You can declare an auxiliary variable to help you decide which is the next direction in which you need to sort your array. 
Somehting like this:

```
self.sortTitle = function () {
    sortArrayAsc = !sortArrayAsc;
    self.arr= self.arr.sort((a, b) => sort(a,b, sortArrayAsc));
}

// ToDo: You can writte this nicer
self.sort = function (a, b, ascending) {
    if(ascending) {
        return a.title > b.title ? 1 : -1;
    } else {
        return a.title > b.title ? -1 : 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to maintain sort type somewhere so that you can toggle it.

There's lots of variants, but something simple like this should work:

```
const ascendingComparator = (a, b) => (a.title > b.title) ? 1 : -1;
const descendingComparator = (a, b) => (a.title > b.title) ? -1 : 1;

self.sortTitle = function (type) {
  if (type === "ascending") {
    self.arr = self.arr.sort(ascendingComparator);
    type = "descending";
  } else {
    self.arr = self.arr.sort(descendingComparator);
    type = "ascending";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a variable to your function and change the conditional

```
self.sortTitle = function (sortOrder) {
    if (sortOrder === 'asc') {
        self.arr= self.arr.sort((a, b) => (a.title > b.title) ? 1 : -1);
    } else { //desc
        self.arr= self.arr.sort((a, b) => (a.title < b.title) ? 1 : -1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a boolean variable that is set to false. In your `sortTitle()` function create a condition that will detect whether it's true or false and then run the opposite when it's true.